# R language issue with mp32wav

Tags: mp3, r, wav

A stupid question. I'm trying [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/warbleR/vignettes/warbleR_workflow_01.html) bioacoustic example but get troubled when trying to convert the downloaded files from mp3 to wav.

I get the famous "Cannot allocate vector of size..." or R simply quits.

No matters if I am using Ubuntu (18) or Windows (10), both installed my 32 GB RAM, i7 12 cores computer.

Any idea about what's happening here?
Thnks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running the 64 bit R (not the i386). I had the same issue on windows, and using the x64 binary solved it.